# Unable to redirect to other page in Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am working on Codeigniter before uploading the site. All of my controllers are working fine on my localhost, but after uploading the site to server when I try to access my sub-domain http://www.advertising.comlu.com/ it works. It means that the controller "school/index" works but when I try to click on other page it redirects to http://error404.000webhost.com/? so please help me.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php RewriteEngine on RewriteCond
%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|css|js|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this .`htaccess` which is I personally recommend for Codeigniter Users

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```